# Maximum Proccessor state Damage hardware?

Tags: windows-7

My CPU and motherboard really heats up during gaming.

- Core 2 Duo
- 4GB RAM
- ATI Radeon 5450
- Windows 7 64-bit

But it doesnt heat if I set maximum processor state to 99% from the power options in control panel.

My question is: can using this setting (99%) damage any hardware? Because after using this setting for 2-3 months, my hard disk died and I had to get a new one.

I've also read that maximum processor state should not be reduced below 100%. What is the reason for that and can doing this damage hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes...this can damage your hardware,because high use of processor state will produce more heat as compare to normal state.It will basically harm when your CPU is at 100% for long periods of time.

Because a combination of heat and flow of electricity through the chip causes changes to the components within the chip at the atomic level, known as [electromigration.](http://www.geek.com/glossary/E/electromigration/) which harm your PC's hardware(basically semiconductor devices).

So i advice you to use less processor state.

Comment: And using less maximum proccessor state (99%) wont damage hardware?

Comment: no..it may be,no one can guarantee that...suggestion is that try to use less processor(if it possible) or high processor state but not for long time